# Error: "Frame callback host must be instance of Magento\Backend\Block\Widget" during Customer Edit

Tags: magento2.2.3

I am getting this error on customer edit page at the admin side:

> Frame callback host must be instance of 
>   Magento\Backend\Block\Widget

I am getting above error for **few users** only.